# EMGU CV 2.4.9 face recognition accuracy issue

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, face-recognition

I have followed the sample code from the code project to create a face recognition system using EMGUCV.  I have trained the database with 2 people and each person has 10 images.  When the webcam detects those people and able to show the name correctly but the problem is the third person whose do not exist in trained database detect by webcam, it will take the nearest face and display the name on it instead of show "Unknown".  How can I improve the accuracy? I have tried to change the threshold value but didn't help. What's going wrong?

```
currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, 
Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

currentFrame.SmoothBlur(320, 240);
gray = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
Rectangle[] facesDetected = face.DetectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 10, new 
Size(50, 50), Size.Empty);

 for (int j = 0; j < facesDetected.Length; j++)
 {
      facesDetected[j].X += (int)(facesDetected[j].Height * 0.15);
      facesDetected[j].Y += (int)(facesDetected[j].Width * 0.22);
      facesDetected[j].Height -= (int)(facesDetected[j].Height * 0.3);
      facesDetected[j].Width -= (int)(facesDetected[j].Width * 0.35);

      result = currentFrame.Copy(facesDetected[j]).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
      result._EqualizeHist();
      currentFrame.Draw(facesDetected[j], new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);

      if (trainingImages.ToArray().Length != 0)
      {
          recog = new LBPHFaceRecognizer(1, 10, 8, 8, 10000);
          //recog = new EigenFaceRecognizer(0, 3500);
          //recog = new FisherFaceRecognizer(0, 3500);
          recog.Train(trainingImages.ToArray(), Names_List_ID.ToArray());
          FaceRecognizer.PredictionResult ER = recog.Predict(result);

                    if (ER.Label == -1)
                    {
                        name = "Unknown";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        name = taglabels[ER.Label];
                    }

         currentFrame.Draw(name, ref font, new Point(facesDetected[j].X - 2, facesDetected[j].Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.Green));

                }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: Any updates on it?

Answer (score 1):

You can threshold the [returned distance/confidence](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/a5a844f2-eee4-af2e-f46c-f8b84ec4cf99.htm). You need a verification set of images, new images of the trained faces and some random faces, get the distance and set the threshold value.

Comment: I could do that, but if you prepare a github repository with the pictures and your own code I could modify it and show how this can be done for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This constructor takes `double threshold` as 5th parameter: `recog = new LBPHFaceRecognizer(1, 10, 8, 8, 10000);`. As I can understand, it's normalised distance multiplied by 100. Strictly speaking you need to adjust it using 10 additional "Unknown" photos, but set it to something between 50 or 70 and check again. Good luck!